# Reflection: Make a Consumer<A> when A could dynamically be any class?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I know to create an object dynamically of any class, I can do

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("fully equalified name");
Object o = c.getDeclaredConstructor(TypeParams).newInstance();
```

But say now I need to create a Consumer and pass it to a method. It is not enough to just pass in the raw type Consumer because that method (given to me) internally needs to figure out A using reflection.

Is there a way to do so in Java?

Comment: Pass it a `Supplier<A>` or `Function<Param, A>` to create the object. e.g. `MyClass::new`

Comment: Perhaps you could post the code of the method that needs to figure out A (and the way you plan to call it) and we can suggest the best Java  idiom to address it unless you have clear how to do it

Answer (score 2):

The [erased nature of generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) makes what you want to do impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "figure out A" from a `Consumer<A>` in general.  Additionally, you *cannot* do anything reflectively that would not be equivalent to creating a raw Consumer.

You will almost certainly need to explicitly pass `Class` objects around.

Comment: You can use less reflection if you use a Supplier or Function to create the object.

Comment: This is actually not true. One can use this library to figure out A. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/TypeUtils.html#getRawType-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.reflect.Type-

Comment: I said "in general." You might be able to do it in specific cases, but there are absolutely instances where erasure means you straight up can't, and I don't think you should even if you could.